# How can I solve an implicit equation without the symbolic toolbox?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, equation-solving

I have an equation like this:

```
(5+x)^2/15+(x-4)^2/10=100
```

Can MATLAB solve this equation directly, without having access to the symbolic toolbox? If it can not do this, how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but requires some hand work.

Your function is a polynomial:

```
x^2/6 - (2*x)/15 + 49/15 = 100
```

When pulling the `100` to the left hand side, we can find the `roots`:

```
roots([1/6 -2/15 -1451/15])
ans =
   24.4948
  -23.6948
```

where the argument is specified as the prefactors in decreasing order of power.

Code with which I found the polynomial (requires the Symbolic Math toolbox):

```
syms x
fun = (5+x)^2/15+(x-4)^2/10-100;
f = simplify(fun);
```

Answer (score -2):

How about using an anonymous function:

```
f=@(x)(5+x)^2/15+(x-4)^2/10-100;
X0=1; % initial guess
x_out=fzero(f,X0);
```

Comment: That will give you only one of its solutions, not both.